# 502 Bad gateway nginx with gunicorn & django

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I'm deploying django project using gunicorn and nginx. My nginx setting is,

```
server {
listen 8000;
server_name 0.0.0.0;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
        root /home/gagan/saporawebapp;
}

location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/gagan/saporawebapp/saporawebapp.sock;
}
}
```

when i run

```
sudo nginx -t
```

It shows that setup is correct . Then i started gunicorn using

```
gunicorn --daemon --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gagan/saporawebapp/saporawebapp.sock saporawebapp.wsgi
```

Then nginx is showing 502 bad gateway. Corresponding error log is,

```
2019/10/08 07:51:34 [emerg] 3988#3988: open()     "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/saporawebapp" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
2019/10/08 07:59:54 [crit] 4278#4278: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 42.108.169.252, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock:/signup/", host: "157.245.108.160:8000"
2019/10/08 08:05:19 [crit] 4278#4278: *5 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 42.108.169.252, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock:/signup/", host: "157.245.108.160:8000"
2019/10/08 08:06:24 [crit] 4744#4744: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 42.108.169.252, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock:/signup/", host: "157.245.108.160:8000"
2019/10/08 08:14:47 [alert] 5279#5279: 768 worker_connections are not enough
2019/10/08 08:14:47 [error] 5279#5279: *763 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 157.245.108.160, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://157.245.108.160:8000/signup/", host: "157.245.108.160:8000"
2019/10/08 09:49:53 [crit] 11601#11601: *1 connect() to unix:/home/gagan/saporawebapp/saporawebapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 42.108.169.252, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/gagan/saporawebapp/saporawebapp.sock:/", host: "157.245.108.160:8000"
```

Comment: Could you provide gunicorn logs? `sudo service gunicorn status` might give you some clues.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo This command gives `gunicorn.service not found`

Comment: but i'm not using gunicorn from a service script

Comment: Oh I see, seem like you're start gunicorn manually. I think you can stop that gunicorn process.. try to run it without daemon flag to see is if there any response from gunicorn.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo In that case, gunicorn is working correctly. I guess the main error is due to absence of .sock file

Comment: That's crazy @@.. one thing might need you to confirm is is these logs is real logs or you've already updated it? because I see that on your nginx settings, the sock file path is `/home/gagan/saporawebapp/saporawebapp.sock`, but in the logs, it's different: `/home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject.sock`.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo if you see time of error log the last updated error contains right path while earlier are due to typos

Comment: if gunicorn running without any error, the sock file should be right there.. @@

Comment: @ToanQuocHo thanks for this fruitful discussion, you are righr